# Django: How display effectively data in my template?

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I save users availability in my database in the form of numbers. **1** user is available, **0** not available. For example if a user is available Monday morning and evening but not during the day, in my database I will have "***101***" 
Now I want to show to my users their availabilities. 
My idea was that for each case, I will create and show them a different image.
Unfortunately, there is too much possibilities for 7 days.

My question is how can I display effectively this data in my template ?

I started to write my views, here it is:

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
    try:
        name = coach.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except coach.DoesNotExist:
        name = coach(user=request.user)
    objs = Lesson.objects.all().filter(mycoach = name)
    args = {'objs': objs}
    if name.monday=="111" and name.tuesday=="111" and name.wednesday=="111" and name.thursday=="111" and name.friday=="111" and name.saturday=="111" and name.sunday=="111" :
        args['image_url'] = static('img/111111111111111111111.pdf')
    if name.monday=="011" and name.tuesday=="111" and name.wednesday=="111" and name.thursday=="111" and name.friday=="111" and name.saturday=="111" and name.sunday=="111" :
        args['image_url'] = static('img/011111111111111111111.pdf')

    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Welcome to your profile')
    return render(request, 'Task.html', args)
else:
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Generate an image name

We can "generate" the name of the image URL by "joining" the configuration of the days together, like:

```
args['image_url'] = static(
    'img/{}{}{}{}{}{}{}.pdf'.format(
        name.monday,
        name.tuesday,
        name.wednesday,
        name.thursday,
        name.friday,
        name.saturday,
        name.sunday
    )
)
```

But this thus still means that you will need to generate *2<sup>21</sup>=2'097'152* images.

## Generating a list of images

So I wonder if it is not more efficient to display seven images (one image after each other), and thus see it as a *list* of seven images, and each image has eight possibilities. So we "ship" the view as:

```
args['image_urls'] = {
    k: static('img/{}.pdf'.format(getattr(name, k)))
    for k in ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
}
```

That would mean that the template looks something like:

```
<!-- my schedule -->
<img src="{{ image_urls.monday }}">
<img src="{{ image_urls.tuesday }}">
<img src="{{ image_urls.wednesday }}">
<img src="{{ image_urls.thursday }}">
<img src="{{ image_urls.friday }}">
<img src="{{ image_urls.saturday }}">
<img src="{{ image_urls.sunday }}">
```

Then you only need to generate eigh images: `000.pdf`, `001.pdf`, `010.pdf`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have all the possible images ready, you can get the image path like this:

```
args['image_url'] = static('img/{}{}{}{}{}{}{}.pdf'.format(
    name.monday, name.tuesday, name.wednesday, name.thursday, name.friday, name.saturday, name.sunday
))
```

Or you could do some dynamic representation in HTML/CSS/javascript in your template. Coloring some table or generating some graph using a js library accessing your data in your template: `{{name.monday.0}}` for Monday morning availability, etc...

See [Django template language doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language).